# How to go to another page if password is correct vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to route to the page "customers" if the password entred by the user(in this form) is correct, otherwise show an error message

```
       <v-card-text>
        <v-form>  
         <v-text-field
            id="password"
            label="Password"
            name="password"
            prepend-icon="mdi-lock"
            type="show1 ? 'text' : 'password'"/>
        </v-form>
    </v-card-text>

      <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer />
        <v-btn color="primary" :to="{name:'customers'}">Login</v-btn>  // I want to add a condition if the password is correct , then go to "customers"
      </v-card-actions>
```

I specify that I configured all necessary routes.

What should I write in the  part ?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How do you check whether the password is correct or not? Do you make any Axios call?

Comment: Can you post all of the relevant code.. including the watcher or method you're using to ensure the password is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should make a method in your component and use the `$router.push` method to change route after checking if password is correct:

```
async checkPassword () {
  if (await checkPasswordWithYourApi(this.password)) {
    this.$router.push({name:'customers'})
    return
  }
  this.showErrors()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have questions : The method "checkPassword()" calls itself ("if (await checkPassword(this.password))") ??  and why there is nothing in the return statement ?

Comment: Yes sorry, those are two different functions, I edited my code. checkPassword is the method in your component that will be called on button click. checkPasswordWithYourApi is another function that calls your API